# How can we subtract bill amount from account balance in a same table onclicking pay button

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

This image has a table having account balance and bill amount and pay button. On clicking pay button values should get subtracted and final account balance should updated in the table.

Comment: Where is the code you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand I'd say you would want to write something like:

```
account_balance -= bill_amount;
```

...and then display the new account_balance.

You might need to modify the syntax of that depending on whether you're doing this in java, JavaScript, or jsp.  It also might be done on the server side and require a page refresh, or maybe in an Ajax call... or maybe it's just a few lines of JavaScript that only update what's being displayed on the page.  The possibilities are endless.

Comment: While I understand that you wish to be helpful, please try to avoid answering questions that do not fit the guidelines outlined in our [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).